# State resets on refresh in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, local-storage

My Next.js app has these dynamic pages: `products/[category]/[subcategory]`. They all use same component - `ProductsList` with sorting functionality. I update state for `sortingWay` in this component, to route between these pages.

From Next docs:

> When navigating to the same page in Next.js, the page's state will
> not be reset by default as react does not unmount unless the parent
> component has changed.

It works fine, but when `sortingWay` has value and I refresh a page, it resets the state. I'm trying to keep `sortingWay` in `localStorage`, it's not working.

`[category].js` (`[subcategory].js` almost a same)

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import ProdList from '../../../components/ProdList';
import React from "react";

export default function SubCategory({ products }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const category = router.query.category;

  const filtered = products.filter(product => category === product.category);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Товари підкатегорії {category}</h1>
      <ProdList data={filtered}/>
    </>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/products`);
  const data = await response.json();

  return {
    props: {
      products: data
    }
  }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/products');
  const data = await response.json();

  const paths = data.map(product => {
    return {
      params: { 
        category: product.category,
      },
    }
  })
  
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
  }
}
```

`ProductList.jsx` component

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import ProductItem from '../ProductItem';
import { productList } from './styles';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';

export default function ProdList({ data }) {
  const [ sortingWay, setSortingWay ] = useState('');
  const [ productsList, setProductList ] = useState(data);

  const router = useRouter();
  const { pathname, query } = router
  const category = router.query.category;
  const subCategory = router.query.subCategory;

  useEffect(() => {
    setSortingWay('')
  }, [router.query.subCategory])

  useEffect(() => {
    setProductList(data)
  }, [router.query.category, router.query.subCategory])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    addEventListener('beforeunload', event => {
      const data = window.localStorage.getItem('sorting___Way');
      if(data.length > 0 ) setSortingWay(data) ;
    })
    
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('sorting___Way', sortingWay);
    setSortingWay(sortingWay) 
  }, [sortingWay]);

  // sorting
  const calcSalePrice = (price, sale) => {
    const normalized = parseInt(price.replace(/\s+/g, ''));
    return (normalized / 100) * (100 - sale);
  } 

  const sortByPriceAscending = () => {
    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const priceA = calcSalePrice(a.price, a.sale);
      const priceB = calcSalePrice(b.price, b.sale);
      return priceA - priceB;
    })
  }
  
  const sortByPriceDescending = () => {
    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const priceA = calcSalePrice(a.price, a.sale);
      const priceB = calcSalePrice(b.price, b.sale);
      return priceB - priceA;
    })
  }

  const sortBySale = () => data.sort((a, b) => b.sale - a.sale);

  const sortByDefault = () => data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

  // https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing
  const shallowRoute = (targetValue) => {
    if (category && !subCategory) {
      return router.push(`/prod/${category}/?sortBy=${targetValue}`, undefined, { shallow: true })
    } else if (category && subCategory) {
      return router.push(`/prod/${category}/${subCategory}/?sortBy=${targetValue}`, undefined, { shallow: true })
    }
  }
  
  // handler
  const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { value } = target;
    
    if (value === "asc") {
      setProductList(sortByPriceAscending());
    } else if (value === "des") {
      setProductList(sortByPriceDescending()); 
    } else if (value === "sale") {
      setProductList(sortBySale());
    } else if (value === "default") {
      setProductList(sortByDefault());
    }

    setSortingWay(value);
    shallowRoute(value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <FormControl variant="standard" sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
      <InputLabel id="sort-products-label">Сортувати</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="sort-products-label"
        id="sort-products"
        value={sortingWay}
        label="Сортувати"
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <MenuItem value={"asc"}>За зростанням ціни</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={"des"}>За спаданням ціни</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={"sale"}>За знижками</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={"default"}>За замовчуванням</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
    
      <div>
        {
          productsList.map(product => 
            <ProductItem 
              key={product.id} 
              id={product.id} 
              subCategory={product.subCategory}
              title={product.title} 
              price={product.price} 
              image={product.image}
              sale={product.sale}
            />
          )
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of any other issues;

It looks like you're only getting the data on `beforeunload`.

Comment: am i doing something wrong? i'm really don't get it

Comment: if you're only getting the data from localstorage when closing the page, how could you ever use it on the page...

Comment: thank you. I just need to save my state on refreshing page, but not on routing... Think, I just must to learn more about browser